# Retrieving new Firebase access token for REST services in .NET from Google auth service

Tags: c#, rest, google-api, firebase, google-api-dotnet-client

After a change of firebase authorization system, I'm trying to retrieve access token in c# from google auth server.

According to new documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth#section-api-usage

I created something similar in c#:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
[...]
async Task<string> GetToken()
{
    GoogleCredential credential;
    using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("gckey.json",
        System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(
            new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database" }
            );
    }

    ITokenAccess c = credential as ITokenAccess;
    return await c.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
}
```

gckey.json is key file downloaded from Google Developer console for specific firebase project.

Code works fine, but it returns token that is not working with firebase, I have tried:
`https://fiery-torch-xxxx.firebaseio.com/.json?access_token=retrived token`

but I receive:
`"error" : "Permission denied."`

What am I doing wrong? Or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this to work after I included "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" in the scopes

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
[...]
async Task<string> GetToken()
{
    GoogleCredential credential;
    using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("gckey.json",
        System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(
            new string[] { 
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database", 
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" }
            );
    }

    ITokenAccess c = credential as ITokenAccess;
    return await c.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
}
```

I discovered this while reading the following google group thread:

[Permission denied error when using Google Oauth2 access token](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/s0wtW8wCwl8/y1N094SOAwAJ)

Comment: This is what I'm going through now. Do you have to get a new token before every call to firebase? Or is this code run only once?

Answer (score 1):

I read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#auth) and it states the the `url` parameter should be "auth" not "access_token". Can you try that?

Comment: Unfortunately not, response is: "Could not parse auth token.".
I believe that auth is relic after old authorizing system, described in old documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/

Comment: Did you try firebase support?

Comment: Firebase support responses are a little bit slow currently. I believe it is because of fusion with google.